# Java private static final field and anonymous inner classes vs. Kotlin const val and object expressions/declarations

Tags: java, class, oop, object, kotlin

Let's say I have a Kotlin interface:

```
interface Dog {
    fun walk()
}
```

I want to create an [Kotlin object of this class with slight modifications](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html), like so:

```
val poodle : Dog = object : Dog {

    override fun walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I also want to add a what is equivalent to a private static final field in Java to this object, like so (**this is a working example in Java**):

```
Dog poodle = new Dog() {

    private static final String POODLE_FASHION = ...

    @Override
    public walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I read that a private const val is equivalent to this in Kotlin. I tried to do the following **(this is an example in Kotlin that is NOT working)**:

```
val poodle : Dog = object : Dog {

    private const val POODLE_FASHION = ...

    override fun walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I did this, I got the following error in Android Studio: **Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects**.

Could someone explain why the Java version works, but the Kotlin version doesn't? How do I do this for Kotlin (I tried companion object already, but got the error **Modifier 'companion' is not applicable inside 'local class'**)? Note I don't want to do the following because I want `POODLE_FASHION` to live inside `val poodle` as I am going to create other Dog objects with slight modification as well (`val pug`, `val chihuahua`, etc.):

```
private const val POODLE_FASHION = ...

val poodle : Dog = object : Dog {

    override fun walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
val poodle : Dog = object : Dog {

    private const val POODLE_FASHION = ...

    override fun walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this example, there's really no reason at all `POODLE_FASHION` needs to be static or const.  It can just be a normal `val`, and it won't cost you anything extra.

That said, it sounds like you ought to have a `Poodle` class, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between an object expression and an object declaration.

- `val poodle = object: Dog { ... }` is an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions). It creates an anonymous object. It's the equivalent of writing `Dog poodle = new Dog() { ... }` in Java.
- `object Poodle: Dog { ... }` is an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations). It creates a singleton object, and is roughly equivalent to creating a Java class that is limited to only having one instance.

The Kotlin documentation states that `const val` properties must be "top-level, or member of an object declaration or a companion object." (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants). They are not valid in object expressions.

The following object declaration should work fine:

```
object Poodle : Dog {
    private const val POODLE_FASHION = ...

    override fun walk() {
        ...
    }
}
```

One important reason for the distinction is that an object expression doesn't declare a new type (though, in Java terms, it does result in an anonymous class).

- `val poodle = object: Dog { ... }` creates a variable of type `Dog`. There is no such type as `Poodle`.
- `object: Poodle: Dog { ... }` creates an object of type `Poodle`. This is a new type which is a subtype of `Dog`.

This difference is important, because in Kotlin a `const val` property always belongs to a type. `MyClass.MY_CONST_VAL` is valid, but accessing it as `MyClass().MY_CONST_VAL` is an error and would not work. As a result, a `const val` property on an anonymous object would always be effectively private to that object.

I can't see a technical reason why it wouldn't be possible to allow `const val` properties on anonymous objects (`static final` compile-time constant fields are allowed in Java inner classes), but their usefulness would be severely limited and it just isn't part of the Kotlin language spec.